# Evolution white text on white background

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, evolution, gtk3

I'm using Evolution 3.28.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 with "Adwaita-dark" theme.

The email I receive are white text on white background.

I don't understand why since the original email is black text on white background and if evolution is modifying the text color why not the background color ?

How can I fix this please ?

(I think it was working last week since I don't remember being annoyed by this kind of problem on all my emails).

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem about 2 weeks ago; all of a sudden, I had old emails that I couldn't read unless I temporarily switched to a light theme. So far, I have not found a fix, although I'm tempted to try the Flatpak version just because it's newer.

Comment: Switching to v3.34.1 via Flatpak has solved this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @ajgringo619 I updated the app by using flatpak and it seems to work.